# Regular expression in batch

Tags: batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

I have the following code in powershell:

`if($url -match "^https://www.youtube"`)

As I can perform the same check in batch I have tried with the following but nothing:

```
echo %url% | findstr "^https://www.youtube*$" >nul

if %url% == 0 (

echo la variables es correcta

) else (

echo la varaible no es correcta

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it using [conditional execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html):

```cmd
cmd /V /C echo(!url!| findstr /I "^https://www\.youtube.\" > nul && (
    echo la variable es correcta
) || (
    echo la variable no es correcta
)
```

Because:

- you are checking the wrong variable (`if %url% == 0`), you should use `if %ErrorLevel% == 0` or `if %ErrorLevel% equ 0`, or even `if not ErrorLevel 1` (which is also true for `ErrorLevel` values less than zero, but `findstr` does not return such anyway); a nice alternative is [conditional execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html);
- `echo %url%` will be problematic when `%url%` contains special characters, hence [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is used to avoid that, enabled by [`cmd /V`](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) and applied by `!url!` instead of `%url%`;
- [`echo`](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html) might have trouble with certain values of `!url!`, which can be avoided by writing `echo(!url!`; also a trailing <kbd>space</kbd> in front of the pipe symbol (`|`) would be echoed, hence just remove it;
- URLs are usually case-insensitive, hence do search/compare case-insensitively as well, using [`findstr /I`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html);
- the `.` in the URL is meant to be a literal character, hence escape it in the search string like `\.`;
- the `*$` suffix you used is wrong, it should read `.*$`, but it is not needed anyway; I would append a literal dot (`\.`) though to not match something like `https://www.youtubefake.net/`, for instance;

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SuperUser.

If you are trying to confirm that some text starts with "https://www.youtube", you don't need the `*$` at the end. And I'm not sure why you are comparing `%url% == 0` after doing the `findstr`. Checking the `errorlevel` will tell you want you want to know. This code does what I think you are trying to accomplish.

```
SET /p url=Enter a URL:

echo %url% | findstr "^https://www.youtube" >nul

if errorlevel 1 (

echo la varaible no es correcta

) else (

echo la variables es correcta

)
```

Answer (score 0):

From your example, it doesn't look like you need an actual regular expression.
You can use simple string substitution to tell if one string is in another string.

```
if "%url:https://www.youtube=%"=="%url%" ( 
    echo variable is not in string 
) else ( 
    echo variable is in string 
)
```

The syntax is %VAR_NAME:SEARCH_STRING=REPLACE_STRING%

What we are saying here:

1. Substitute "https://www.youtube" with nothing in the variable named ***url***
2. Compare it to one that has not had the substitution done.
3. If they are the same, the string "https://www.youtube" wasn't in the variable.

Caveats:

This method doesn't provide the functionality that the "^" anchor did in powershell.
If the variable *contains* "https://www.youtube" anywhere, your match will be invalid..
for instance.. ***"https://www.senorsuerte.com/value?https://www.youtube"*** would produce a hit when that isn't what you intend to do.

This case is also easy to fix by pre-pending an invalid char to the beginning of each of the strings we are testing.

```
if "*%url:https://www.youtube=%"=="*%url%" ( 
    echo variable is not in string 
) else ( 
    echo variable is in string 
)
```

Note the "*" at the beginning of each string.  The "*" isn't magic.. it just anchors our query for us at the beginning of the string and could be ANY char.